# Will the Main Interface be automatically mapped to my iPad storyboard during deployment?

Tags: ipad, deployment, interface, storyboard, program-entry-point

I'd like to deploy my first Universal app with an iPad specific version to the app store. Everything works well in Xcode, I'm able to manage 2 separate storyboards via my info.plist using the following entries:

- Main storyboard file base name: Main.storyboard
- Main nib file base name (iPad): Main-ipad.storyboard

Then in my Deployment Info I usually switch the Main Interface (**manually**) back and forth between Main and Main-ipad for development purposes.

**Though, what will happen when I'll submit my app (binary) to the app store?  Will the Main Interface be automagically switched based on the user device or do I have to programmatically switch the value based on the current device?** So that the iPad gets the right Main Interface as well as the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - I finally worked that out. Here are the clear and simple steps that you need to follow in order to either: convert an iPhone app into a universal app, or to simply package your universal app prior to submitting the build to the App store:

1. Make sure you select "Universal" for devices in your project Deployment info under the General tab.
2. Create a XIB file (=storyboard) for the iPad. You can either copy past the iphone one  or start from scratch. Name it something like "Main-ipad.storyboard" for example.
3. Now you need to manually do a bunch of stuff which I don't really understand why xcode does not do it automatically for us since they've introduced that "universal" project thing.

   3.1 Go to your info.plist file and add the following entry to tell your project that you're using a seperate storyboard for the iPad. Add "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" as a key and then your XIB file name "Main-ipad" without any extension.

   3.2 Make sure you have the original XIB file (iphone) well setup. It should be "Main storyboard file base name" and the value something like "Main".
4. Now try to run your app in the simulator on iphone and then ipad see if it picks up the right storyboard.

Done!

**Notes:** Make sure to select the right key because I had "Main nib file base name..." instead of "Main storyboard file base...". This was generating errors when I was trying to archive and submit the build to the app store even though it was working fine in xcode!